# iOS - how to package an SDK up to not have conflicting filenames with a user's SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stable way to embed open-source code into static library in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149005/stable-way-to-embed-open-source-code-into-static-library-in-ios)

I am not sure if this question belongs here. Please instruct me if it does not.

I am building an SDK which has Reachability.h and Reachability.m files. If a user drops my code into his own, and if he has files with the same names, he will have to rename my files or his own for it to work. Is there an elegant way around this such that the SDK could always be dropped in without causing any conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're providing source, then you can safely include Reachability (or whatever), but provide a target in the project file that doesn't include them. If you're providing a built library but not source code, then leave out the parts like Reachability that are readily available and provide instructions on how to get them and add them to the target project. Alternately, provide two (or more) versions of your library: one with Reachability and one without.

Answer (score 1):

Change the names. Most reusable third-party Cocoa code employs three-letter prefixes (e.g. my own company uses FZA) on its class, function and type names.

Comment: -1 for a solution leading into ridiculous code duplication.

Comment: @till I'm going to assume it was pasting in Apple's sample code that really led to the ridiculous code duplication.